# как установить пакет graphicx в miktex?

Tags: latex, tex

Как установить файл graphicx.sty в Miktex 4.9?
В репозитории СТАН нет установочного файла graphicx.ins, есть только sty и dtx.

1. Текст https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions ... ex-windows
   написан не четко:
   "Сделайте новый пакет известным для MiKTeX: обновите базу данных имен файлов MiKTeX. Для этого нажмите «Пуск/Программы/MiKTeX 2.x/Maintenance/Settings» (или аналогичный), чтобы перейти к параметрам MiKTeX, нажмите кнопку «Обновить FNDB». Установка завершена."
   У меня ни какой кнопки «Обновить FNDB» нет.
2. Пробовал установить через создание корневого каталога, но для обновления пакетов в Miktex не понятно как указать путь к каталогу с файлом sty.
3. Вероятно надо создать локальный репозиторий пакетов. Но рекомендаций для этого способа установки пакетов нет.

Comment: Чем Вас не устраивает пакет, который идет в дистрибутиве миктеха? Вы его руками удалили из системы? В крайнем случае, просто положите стилевой (sty) файл рядом с Вашим документом...